# Using a reference in recursion is causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++, recursion, reference

[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16d1433620f71e88)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
        vector<int> node_connections;
        string content;
};



int find_remaining_paths(node & a)         //reference causing crash
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.node_connections.size(); i++)
    {
        if (a.node_connections[i] != -1)    //if not visited
        {
            a.node_connections[i] = -1;     //path marked as visited
            return i;                       //return index in nodes
        }
    }
    return -1;                              //no paths remaining
}

void find_euler_circuits(vector<node> & nodes, node & a)
{
    cout << a.content << " ";
    int temp = find_remaining_paths(a);    //finds next path in vector, if one exists
    if (temp+1)                            //if there's a remaining path in node a
    {
        find_euler_circuits(nodes, nodes[a.node_connections[temp]]);  //crashes here
    }
    return;
}



int main()
{
    vector<node> nodes;

    node a;      //nodes[0]
    node b;      //nodes[1]
    node c;      //nodes[2]
    node d;      //nodes[3]

    a.content = "a";
    b.content = "b";
    c.content = "c";
    d.content = "d";

    a.node_connections.push_back(1);        // a --> b
    a.node_connections.push_back(3);        // a --> d
    b.node_connections.push_back(2);        // b --> c
    c.node_connections.push_back(0);        // c --> a

    nodes.push_back(a);
    nodes.push_back(b);
    nodes.push_back(c);
    nodes.push_back(d);

    find_euler_circuits(nodes, nodes[0]);   // a is starting node
}
```

I'm trying to find all euler paths in a multigraph. In this case using nodes to represent vertices. Here's the idea:

For example:

```
nodes[0] holds node a
nodes[1] holds node b
nodes[2] holds node c
nodes[3] holds node d


Connections:

a --> b
a --> d
b --> c
c --> a
```

So node 'a' holds index integers 1,3 (b,d)

node 'b' holds index integer 2 (c)

node 'c' holds index integer 0 (a)

Using recursion, the program spans the graph:

```
(a[0] = b) -> (b[0] = c) -> (c[0] = a) -> (a[1] = d)
```

(I know this method doesn't find a euler path, but I have to get it working first)

The logic itself is working fine, if I remove the references & then it just loops forever a[0] -> b[0] -> c[0] -> a[0] -> etc., but with the reference it crashes right after reaching

```
find_euler_circuits(nodes, nodes[a.node_connections[temp]]);
```

Can anyone tell me why that causes a segmentation fault in the above program?
The reference that's causing it to crash is in

```
int find_remaining_paths(node & a)   //loops forever without &, crashes with &
```

Also, the recursion should stop as soon as it reaches a node that has no paths left, but that's not what the problem is because it crashes after accessing one node

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Good luck - people will rarely follow a link to "my program". Better to reduce your problem to an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), both in terms of debugging it yourself and getting help here.

Comment: I did, my program is actually much larger. I reproduced the problem minimally.. or am i missing something here? I changed the link name from "my program" to "mcve"

Comment: Again, people generally won't follow a link, ideally you should post the code in the question. It's not just laziness, having a link defeats the archival nature of SO because at some point the link will break and the question/answers will become worthless.

Comment: I see, I put the code in my post

Comment: BTW, the test `if (temp+1) { ... }` "works" but is such non-standard code that your code reviewers (if you have any) will put your head up on a pike.  `if (temp == 0)` is easier to understand and only costs you one additional character to type.

Comment: If temp == 0, that means the index for **nodes[0]** was returned. I'm returning **-1** whenever a path can't be found

Comment: Then (temp != -1) should be the test.  Fine.  temp+1 as a test is not easily readable by people because it is a completely unexpected way of writing the test.  Its a readability issue, that's all.

Comment: @xyz, You're changing the `node`'s connection vector entry to `-1` within  `find_remaining_paths`.  Trying to index -1 within the `nodes` vector is UB. Try adding a print statement right after the call to `find_remaining_paths` that prints out `a.node_connections[temp]`.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?  The problem occurs trying to process the very first node, so you don't have to do much single-stepping to see what's going on.. Alejandro and davidbak have described the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the part of your question about why "removing references" makes it loop forever: Without the reference (`&`) on the prototype of `find_euler_circuits` so it looks like `find_euler_circuits(vector<node> nodes, node a)` *if that is what you mean* (*) then you're making *copies* of the vector and the node - which makes a copy of the vector *within it* - every time you make the call, thus the value you're setting to -1 isn't in the array you think it is.

As to why it crashes when you *have* the references - in `find_remaining_paths` you set `a.node_connections[i]` to -1, then return i, then in the caller you then reference `a.node_connections[i]` ... which is -1.  At least, that's how I'm reading the code...

(*) You really should also provide the code that is what you get when you "remove references", whatever that may mean.

Comment: I know why it loops forever, my only question is why adding a reference is causing it to crash. Without the reference it only makes local copies which is why I need to reference it. Also I added the code to my post

Comment: I think OP is referring to the ref qualifier on `find_remaining_paths` though, which still makes a copy of the `node` and does not have any visible effects outside of that function call, even if the vector were passed in by modifiable reference.